# How to get the most frequent value over partitions in Polars?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, python-polars

I'm trying to use Polars to get the most frequent value in a column of a DataFrame, for each category, and this category is given by multiple other columns (i.e., using a composite primary key).

For example, I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

**Input**

| index | pk_1 | pk_2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | x | 42 |
| 1 | b | y | 69 |
| 2 | a | x | 36 |
| 3 | b | x | 12 |
| 4 | a | x | 36 |

And I would like the output to be:

**Output**

| index | pk_1 | pk_2 | value | majority_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | x | 42 | 36 |
| 1 | b | y | 69 | 69 |
| 2 | a | x | 36 | 36 |
| 3 | b | x | 12 | 12 |
| 4 | a | x | 36 | 36 |

I have tried using `.mode()` with `.over()` but it returns an exception:

> exceptions.ComputeError: The length of the window expression did not match that of the group.

Code I've tried using:

```
def get_majority_value(primary_keys: list):
    return (
        pl.col("value")
        .mode()
        .over(primary_keys)
        .alias('majority_value')
    )

frame.with_columns([
    get_majority_value(primary_keys=['pk1', 'pk2'])
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Polars' `.mode()` expression can return multiple values if there is a tie (more than one mode).

So we have to aggregate the results from `.mode()` in a `list`, and then we can get the first element of that list using the `.arr` extension. For example:

```
def get_majority_value(primary_keys: list):
    return (
        pl.col("value")
        .drop_nulls() # Use this if you don't want to consider "None" as a possible mode
        .mode()
        .list()
        .over(primary_keys)
        .arr.get(0)
        .alias('majority_value')
    )

frame.with_columns([
    get_majority_value(primary_keys=['pk1', 'pk2'])
])
```

### Edit

As @jqurious has pointed out in the comments, there is a cleaner way to perform the same thing, using `.first()`:

```
def get_majority_value(primary_keys: list):
    return (
        pl.col("value")
        .drop_nulls() # Use this if you don't want to consider "None" as a possible mode
        .mode()
        .first()
        .over(primary_keys)
        .alias('majority_value')
    )
```

Comment: Are you looking for `.first()`? e.g. `pl.col("value").mode().first().over(primary_keys)`